# How to map two tables records to list of java objects

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have two tables author and blogs in postgresql DB, I want to retrieve records and map/bind to List object using simple JDBC client, below are table and object details

Schema details

```
author (TABLE)
id VARCHAR(10)
name VARCHAR(200)
dob VARCHAR(200)
 blogsv (TABLE)
id VARCHAR(10)
author VARCHAR(10)
subject VARCHAR(200)
content VARCHAR(200)
```

Author table

[image: Author table]

Blog table

[image: Blog table]

```
public class Author{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private List<Blogs> blogs; // Bind related blog records
}

public class Blog{
    private String id;
    private String authorId;
    private String subject;
    private Date content;
}
```

I am currently fetching all author record and creating author object first and then query blogs by iterating author object created earlier and create blog objects map it to author. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6afb94/2)

I am not able resize the images, hence occupying most of the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guideline which could be useful for design code.

1. On DB level

   a) `blogsv`, column `author` should be `int` and is foreign-key for `author`

    (`FK` need to be marked on `create-table`)

   It's working even as `varchar` but DB-rules for consistent design are broken

   b) Better to use one query with join to retrieve all date in one piece

`select author.id, author.name, author.dob,`
`blogsv.id blogId,blogsv.subject, blogsv.content`
`from author left join blogsv on author.id = blogsv.author`

[image: sql]

2. On Java Side

a) Use correspondent type on mapping (sql-columns to java)

```
public class Author{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    //could also create by default an empty list for each author;
    private List<Blogs> blogs = new ArrayList<Blogs>(); 
    // Bind related blog records
}

public class Blog{
    private int id;
    //do not need since it's on top level (nested with author)
    //private String authorId;
    private String subject;
    private Date content;
}
```

b) Enhance Logic

```
//better to use a map for easy access to author by id
Map<Integer, Author> authorMap = new HashMap<>();
//after retrieve data from sql
//loop each record 
//check if author is key on Map
//NO: create new author 
authorMap.put(id, new Author(...))
//YES: retrieve author 
Author a = authorMap.get(id)
//add blog detail if any (fields are not null)
//need also to retrieve from java associate blogList
a.getBlogList().add(blogDetails)
//end loop
```

Note: `id` is defined as `varchar` fine till a point but mainly `PK` should be `integer` and also `autoincrement` in most of cases

Answer (score 0):

### JPA provider

In long run, it will be beneficial to use a JPA provider with corresponding entities

1. Map the SQL tables/relations to Java entities
2. Use the JPA provider to manage transactions, CRUD operations, and prepared statements(to prevent SQL injection attack)

Reference [EclipseLink](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria)

### How

1. Create `javax.persistence.` entities(`@Entity`) as per the sql table structure for Author and Blog
2. Define `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")` in `Author` for `List<Blog> blogs`
3. Define `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="author")` in `Blog` for `private Author author`